# Android: Full sized text on button

Tags: android, android-button

How can I increase text size in Button, without changing Button size. In other words i want to display text in whole Button surface. And i want to achive that in java code not in XML file.

Answer (score 0):

In java class you can do that as follows

```
Button bt = new Button(this);
bt.setTextSize(12);
```

and in xml

```
<Button
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
```

Note: **Recommended dimension type for text is "sp" for scaled-pixels.**

Comment: I'm not trying to just resize text, but I want to display my text on whole button without any space between text and button borders.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = new Button(this);

// set the text size in the second parameter. I have set 20 for the sake of your understanding.
button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
```

Let me know if it works.